Display custom message after completing org-babel-tangle
I'm using org-babel-tangle to tangle one of my org file into an the emacs config file. After completion, I get a message showing how many blocks have been tangled like Tangled 48 code blocks from My-Org-File.org.
But along with this,

I want to be able to display the time it took to complete the tangling. Searching around I found this answer which does that, but it doesn't show the number of code blocks evaluated.
I also want to be able to display the number of files that have been tangled

I want my message to look like - Tangled 48 blocks from My-ORG-File.org into 3 files in 0.087563 sec
Is it possible to add the number of code blocks evaluated to the defadvice mentioned in above link or by any other means?

In principle, it is possible: org-babel-tangle knows how many blocks it tangled (see the variable block-counter), and it knows the list of output files it created (or overwrote) in the variable patch-collector which is the return value. The elapsed time can be added as in the link. The  main problem is that block-counter is a local variable so when the function returns, it goes poof and the value disappears, so you cannot get that value with an advice. The cleanest way is to modify org-babel-tangle to return the value along with the patch-collector. But that forks Org mode...

... so you'll have to maintain the fork in perpetuity. Or you can send an RFE to the Org mode mailing list: if they implement it, then you are off the hook.

Well, I would not like to maintain a fork at this point, but I think that pretty much answers the question. Its not possible to get the count of files at this moment. So, is it possible to customize it to include number of blocks and the time in one message?

You cannot get the number of blocks tangled: org-babel-tangle throws that value away after issuing its message. But you can get the number of output files: it returns the list of such files, so all you have to do is get the length of that list. That can be done with an advice.

So one way to do the fork is to: 1) delete the message call in org-babel-tangle; 2) return a list of two elements: the block-counter and patch-collector. Then write an advice to that does the timing and uses the return value of the modified org-babel-tangle for the rest of the information. The information is there, it's just not  available in its entirety at the same place at the same time.

Or you can leave everything as is, and advise org-babel-tangle more or less as in your link to get the timing and then add the length of the returned list to that and call message to output that information. That is going to overwrite the echo area, so the mesage output from org-babel-tangle that contains the number of tangled blocks, will disappear from there. But it is still available in the *Messages* buffer, so you can get it from there. Not convenient at all, but a nice proof-of-concept.
